# spring-security - delegate to different controllers depending on authenticated or not?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Rather than have a REST controller where within each method I take different actions depending on whether the current user is authenticated I'd like to delegate to completely different controller implementations depending on the authenticated status of the user.

I.e. I'd provide an interface containing a set of method signatures, each with a `@RequestMapping` annotation, and then provide one implementation of this interface to be used for authenticated users and another implementation for non-authenticated users. Some logic would then choose the appropriate implementation for the current user and dispatch to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you have an answer that is working for you, but a possible solution that might be of interest (just for info at this point I guess) is to use Spring custom mapping conditions.

We can define an annotation that we can use to decorate our controllers - maybe something like `@AuthenticatedMapping`

```
@Target( ElementType.TYPE )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthenticatedMapping {}
```

(You could implement this differently, and have an enum value to indicate specific roles etc, could also set it as a METHOD level annotation if you prefer that granularity)

Then you can define a custom `RequestCondition` - this is the class that Spring will use as part of working out the correct handler for a given request (just like for the `@RequestMapping` annotation)

```
public class AuthenticatedMappingRequestCondition implements RequestCondition<AuthenticatedMappingRequestCondition> {


    @Override public AuthenticatedMappingRequestCondition getMatchingCondition( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        AuthenticatedMappingRequestCondition condition = null;
        //Check the user is authenticated, if so return this condition:
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if( (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
            condition = this;
        }
        return condition;
    }

    //
    //TODO other methods need to be implemented here - all pretty simple
    //

}
```

So now we have the mapping condition, we just need to extend the standard Spring `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` so it includes our custom condition when considering mapping decisions:

```
public class AuthenticatedMappingRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Override protected RequestCondition<?> getCustomTypeCondition(Class<?> handlerType) {
        AuthenticatedMapping typeAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, AuthenticatedMapping.class);
        return (typeAnnotation != null) ? new AuthenticatedMappingRequestCondition() : null;
    }
}
```

Once you have wired up the custom condition with Spring, then you can just decorate any controller with your annotation and Spring will use the condition to route requests:

```
@RestController
@AuthenticatedMapping
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AuthenticatedAccountRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/someCommonRequestA")
    public String someCommonRequestA() {
        return "Got authenticated someCommonRequestA";
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AnonymousAccountRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/someCommonRequestA")
    public String someCommonRequestA() {
        return "Got anonymous someCommonRequestA";
    }
}
```

Some caveats:

- You would need to test that the absence of the annotation is enough to route to the anonymous controller - if not, the annotation could be enhanced with an enum of roles allowed - and explicitly add an `@AuthenticatedMapping( Roles.ANONYMOUS )` to that controller
- As it is a single endpoint it doesn't handle specific security stuff, so would still need security stuff put in place, and not 100% that there wouldn't be other considerations for spring-security authentication stuff

Not suggesting its a better approach than what you have, but I had to do custom routing based on subdomain using this approach a while back (I wrote it up [here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/spring-mvc-custom-routing-conditions.html) - which is what the above code is based on), and I found it quite a nice, idiomatic Spring-y solution when I had to roll it out to lots of controller/endpoints as the boilerplate is abstracted to Spring machinery and the controllers are nicely decorated.

Anyways, might be fun to look at if nothing else :)

Comment: I can't say I've tried this - so I can't give an immediate comparison between it and the approach I've already taken. But it looks interesting enough to be worth the bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

I thought this would be easier than it proved. This is my solution.

First rather than an interface I created an abstract class containing the controller requests:

```
@PreAuthorize("this.authorized")
public abstract class AccountRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/someCommonRequestA")
    public abstract String someCommonRequestA();

    public boolean getAuthorized() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();

        return !(authentication == null ||
            authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken);
    }
}
```

The things to note are the `@PreAuthorize` annotation and the `getAuthorized()` method. Then I provided a class to handle forwarding to the appropriate controller:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardingAccountController {
    @RequestMapping("/account/**")
    public String forward(HttpServletRequest request,
            Authentication authentication) {
        String prefix = authentication != null ? "authenticated" : "anonymous";
        String path = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

        // You could do a redirect if you wanted to make explicit to the caller what's going on.
        return "forward:/" + prefix + "/" + path;
    }
}
```

And then I provided authenticated and anonymous implementations to which the actual behavior is delegated depending on the status of the current user.

For authorized users:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authenticated/account")
public class AuthenticatedAccountRestController extends AccountRestController {
    @Override
    public String someCommonRequestA() {
        return "Got authenticated someCommonRequestA";
    }
}
```

For non-authorized users:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/anonymous/account")
public class AnonymousAccountRestController extends AccountRestController {
    @Override
    public String someCommonRequestA() {
        return "Got anonymous someCommonRequestA";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAuthorized() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

See how `AnonymousAccountRestController` turns off the requirement to be authorized by overriding `getAuthorized()`.

The tricky bit was the Spring Security annotation. Initially I thought I'd be able to just annotate `AuthenticatedAccountRestController` with `@Secured(AuthenticatedVoter.IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)`.

However adding annotations on the subclass when the mappings have been defined in the superclass doesn't work - see ["Spring MVC controller inheritance with spring security"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24742295).

So inspired by that SO answer I used `@PreAuthorize` on the superclass in such a way that I could change it's actual behavior in the subclasses.

Also of interest is the difference in the authenticated check in `AccountRestController` and `ForwardingAccountController` - in the latter I don't have to worry about `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` - I get a null for anonymous users.

If you want to experiment you can find these class in the Github repo [auth-dependent-controllers](https://github.com/george-hawkins-aa/auth-dependent-controllers).

Why did I expect things to be simpler? In JAX-RS I was able to achieve something similar with a resource that returned different subresources depending on the status of the user and these subresources handled the actual request. I thought I'd be able to do something fairly similar in Spring.

PS sorry for using authorized and authenticated as if they were interchangeable terms.